# MySQL find behind which rows in `column2` values from `column1` should be inserted to preserve the order of `column2`

Tags: mysql, binary-search

**My Question:**

I'm using MySQL and I have two columns called `column1` and `column2` of equal length. My goal is to find out for each value in `column1` (if it were ordered) where (after which row) it should be inserted into `column2` to preserve the order of `column2` (if it were ordered). As an example, suppose that `column1` and `column2` have the following values:

```
column1 = [1, 2, 2, 4]
column2 = [0, 1, 1, 3]
```

In this case the result that I would want to find would be

```
result = [1, 3, 3, 4]
```

because the first value of `column1` would have to be inserted in `column2` behind row 1, the second and the third values of `column1` would have to be inserted in `column2` behind row 3 and the fourth value of `column1` would have to be inserted in `column2` behind row 4.

**My approach:**

What I can do is create a new column called `values` that is the concatenation of `column1` to `column2` and create a new column called `col` that indicates whether the row originally came from `column1` or `column2`. If I order the results based on both new columns I get the following result:

```
values col
0      col2
1      col1
1      col2
1      col2
2      col1 
2      col1
3      col2
4      col1
```

If I now run the following query on these two columns

```
SELECT values, col, SUM(CASE WHEN col = 'col2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY values, col) AS row
FROM new_table
```

I get the following

```
values col    row
0      col2   1
1      col1   1
1      col2   2
1      col2   3
2      col1   3
2      col1   3
3      col2   4
4      col1   4
```

Selecting from this result the rows that have `col` = `col1` will give me what I am looking for.

I'm sure that there's a better way to do this!